# Perl tests - common parent for tests

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

I have a set of tests, always named `Module.t`, each one starts like this:

```
use 5.026;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::Perl::Critic (-severity => 3);
use Module::Path 'module_path';
use Test::More tests => 8;
use Test::Log4perl;
Test::Log4perl->suppress_logging;

BEGIN { use_ok("My::Module") }
critic_ok(module_path("My::Module"));

... actual tests for this module ...
```

It's done this way because a bunch of modules are not coded very nicely and in effort to refactor stuff as we go, I'm trying to write tests for individual modules over time. Eg. I can't just enable Perl::Critic for all sources cause it will blow up in my face.

I would like to ideally make a "parent" test for all of these so that when me or a different developer wants to write a new test they will always have all the required stuff. Something like:

```
use 5.026;
use strict;
use warnings;

# 6 tests because 2 (use_ok and critic_ok) are already in the parent
use parent ParentTest("My::Module", tests => 6);

... actual tests for this module ...
```

Does perl have a way of doing that?

Disclaimer: I'm a perl noob, so maybe this has a better solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just want a helper module that loads some other modules and runs some initial tests for you.

Something like:

```
# ParentTest.pm
package ParentTest;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::Perl::Critic (-severity => 3);
use Module::Path 'module_path';
use Test::More;
use Test::Log4perl;

sub import {
    my (undef, $module, %args) = @_;

    $args{tests} += 2;

    plan %args;
    Test::Log4perl->suppress_logging;
    use_ok $module;
    critic_ok module_path $module;

    @_ = 'Test::More';
    goto +Test::More->can('import');
}

1
```

Usage would be:

```
use ParentTest "My::Module", tests => 6;
```

This is all untested, but the idea is:

- We want to run some code to set up the initial test plan and run some tests.
- We also want to export everything that `Test::More` exports, so our caller doesn't have to `use Test::More` themselves.
- `use Some::Module @args` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require "Some/Module.pm"; Some::Module->import(@args); }`, so we can just put our custom logic in the `import` method.
- We start by ignoring the first argument (which is a class name because `import` is called as a class method) and assigning the remaining arguments to `$module` and `%args`.
- We increment `$args{tests}` by 2 to account for the two extra tests we perform automatically (if `tests` wasn't passed in, it is implicitly created here).
- We pass `%args` to [`plan` from `Test::More`](https://perldoc.pl/Test::More#I-love-it-when-a-plan-comes-together), which is nice for setting up a test plan outside of the initial `use` line.
- We perform the initial tests.
- We tail call `Test::More::import`, erasing our own stack frame. This makes it look like our caller did `Test::More->import()`, which exports all the `Test::More` utility functions to them.
- The unary `+` in `goto +Test::More->...` has no real effect, but it helps distinguish between the `goto LABEL` and `goto EXPRESSION` syntactic forms. We want the latter interpretation.

Comment: this is perfect, I submitted an edit to add &{} for the goto. I also added code to set/increate tests by 2 as use_ok and critic_ok are 2 tests already. I have not figured out how to make that nicer, can't seem to find a way to convert array to hash in-line without a variable. Feel free to prettify that part :-)) Thanks!

Comment: @lukash I simplified the `tests + 2` logic. Why add `&{ }`?

Comment: `&{ }` was added because without it I get `Bareword found where operator expected at ... line .., near "goto Test::More" (Do you need to predeclare goto?)`

Comment: @melpomene, I agree with lukash. I tested your code with 5.10 to 5.28, and none worked. You need `goto &{ Test::More->can('import') }` or `goto(Test::More->can('import'))` for your code to compile.

Comment: @lukash Should be fixed now. Took me a while to get the prerequisites installed to actually test this code.

Comment: @melpomene didn't know I could use the `+`, looks nicer than `&{ }`. Appreciate the effort.